# UIWebview content not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview as a sub view of a custom view. I have used XIB's for Custom Views. So the hierarchy is as follows:-

ViewController.view -(subview)> SettingsCustomView -(subview)> TermsCustomView -(subview)> UIWebview (in XIB).

I have connected the the delegate method as well as the Outlet perfectly. Everything loads and happens as it should be, and even the methods getting called perfectly without error. Only one thing is missing, content for webview. Its like the content is loading but is not visible.

I did these but none of them shows the content although it loads the content :-

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"terms" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.termWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

and I also tried this :-

```
[self.termWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
```

All the delegate methods getting called the html string is perfect in the first case. Its just that the content seems to be invisible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Clip Subviews or Autoresize Subviews maybe the problem

Comment: Code is correct, it should work, you can check if UIWebView is visible or not stays under some other views etc?

Comment: It is visible. I set the background color of uiwebview. So when I drag I can see the background color.

Comment: I know the problem, please provide the right link. for example you have username or password to pass through the link, get the full path of the link. copy paste your link to any browser, then you can see if the url will change on the address bar as a public URL. that's the URL u need. :)

Comment: Even if I want to load "http://www.google.com" it is not loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I resolved this by adding the delegate method of UIWebview and returning TRUE as follows:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this would resolve your issue because `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` should return TRUE by default anyway, it's not a required method for the protocol it is an optional one which as I have already said returns by default TRUE. So I can't see how this resolved it for you it just doesn't make sense. Did you do anything else?

Comment: Not at all. If I remove this method it again does not work. I know I have UIWebViews in other apps also but I have never came across such a strange issue.

Comment: This makes no sense at all, I believe this could be masking the issue and not really resolving it but I don't believe you provide enough information for users to help properly so if this works fine but I would maybe investigate a little more.

Comment: Actually, on [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) it never says the default is YES

Comment: But then why are you downgrading the answer!